# php://input losing data when changing url to not include index.php

Tags: php, laravel, api-design

So I'm building a custom API endpoint that I need to send data to from Laravel. I'll need a ton of URL's and wanted to do this as clean as possible, while still having to do it from scratch with no framework.

I was trying to create the following endpoint

/api/categories/create/

Now, I can post with Guzzle to /api/categories/create/index.php and get the contents with `file_get_contents('php://input')` just fine. And I know when I remove the index.php it's still posting to the right place because I can send back 'Hello' as a response and I do receive it.`

Kind of stumped as to why `file_get_contents('php://input')` can get the data I'm sending but only when I explicitly specify index.php at the end of the url.

Here's my request, although I don't think the error is coming from this...

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://example.test/'
]);

$course = [
    'title'       => $request->title,
    'description' => $request->description,
    'site'        => $request->site
];

$response = $client->post('api/categories/create', [
    'json' => ['course' => $course]
]);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a `.htaccess` file, which defines `index.php` as single point of access.

the rewrite pattern should be (similar to) `controller/method/id`, for example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # remove trailing slash
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(\d+)$ /index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

followed by further patterns, which rewrite without `id` and also without `method` (defaulting to index).

`api/categories/create` would require pattern alike ~ `^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  /index.php?controller=$1&subject=$2&method=$3 [L,NC,QSA]`. one could also define possible values with a logical `OR` alike `^(.*)/(.*)/(create|read|update|destroy)(/|)$`.

Comment: What are controller method and id for? Would this be assuming I only have one file for the entire API?

Comment: In your example would index.php be at the root then? I currently have /api/categories/create/index.php and /api/categories/destroy/index.php etc

Comment: for example, even Laravel has a `Controller` class: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#defining-controllers ...while this would be a single `index.php`, which can initialize the application and then use plugin controllers, as requested. for example, a directory structure alike `/webroot/index.php` & `/controller/api.php` - while the controllers do not even have to reside within the web-root (still have to be within the server's file-system). most MVC works alike that - while an API has no views.